# Import a github repo in react and received an empty folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, github, npm

I forked TimboKZ's Chonky (https://github.com/TimboKZ/Chonky) and made a little modification to it. Mine is here: https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky-modified

However, when I run 'npm install [https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky-modified.git'](https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky-modified.git%27) I saw no code files installed, but LICENSE, package.json, and README.md these three files. No lib folder exists as it supposed to[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBEf1.png).

So what is going on here?

Comment: I think you forgot to `cd` into the repo and ***then*** simply run `npm install`.

Comment: @DrewReese I did everything in repo. If I do npm install chonky, which I import the original one, it works and shows with a lib, but it does not work with my forked repo

Comment: I don't follow. I just `git clone git@github.com:Lethees/Chonky-modified.git` your repo, `cd`'d into it and ran `npm i` and it all appears to be there. Are you not cloning a copy of the repo to your local machine? Please list all the specific steps you are doing to reproduce the issue you face.